# Cannot Load csv with D3 Promise

Tags: d3.js, promise

I'm loading d3 from this:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Then trying to load a local csv file: ( Partial Code )

```
d3.csv("data.csv").then(function (data) {
            // format the data
            data.forEach(function (d) {
                d.date = parseTime(d.date);
                d.close = +d.close;
            });
```

But getting this in the VS Code console:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at ec (d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js:2:99951)
    at <anonymous> (d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js:2:100075)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\coder\OneDrive\Documents\d3\index.html:40:12)
    --- Promise.then ---
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\coder\OneDrive\Documents\d3\index.html:40:29)
```

The csv is on the same directory as the html file being served.

Comment: It is not best practice to use forEach inside of a promise (which you construct with then). This might be the reason for your bug. Instead try Promise.all to loop over your async array. Read this for the full example and further explanation: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Use slash for the root path `"/data.csv"`
2. Use try / catch for exception handling

```
try {
  const data = await d3.csv("/data.csv");
  data.forEach(...);
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```